# ActiveRecord unknown attribute with polymorphic association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-activerecord

I have the following models

```
 class Business < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_one :name_object, as: :nameable
 end

 class NameObject < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_one :user
   belongs_to :nameable, polymorphic: true
 end
```

However, when I try to build a business with a name and user, like so:

```
 business = Business.new
 business.build_name_object
 business.name_object.build_user
```

Rails throws the error `ActiveRecord::UnknownAttributeError in BusinessesController#new unknown attribute: name_object_id`.

I've created the database with `nameable_id` and `nameable_type` columns for the `name_objects` table, but I don't think I need a `name_object_id` foreign key on the business table as well. What am I missing?

Comment: ActiveRecord::UnknownAttributeError in BusinessesController#new
unknown attribute: name_object_id

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems like since your NameObject `has_one :user`, that the User would be the one that `belongs_to :name_object`, therefore Rails is looking for `name_object_id` to be a field in the user table and its throwing that error. Just a hunch so, maybe, post your User model code.

Comment: Thank you. I got stuck thinking that name_object wasn't initialized and couldn't think past it.